# Difficulties displaying JS function result based on feature field calculations in HTML web page

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I am looking to display a statistic that I derived from a JS function, called "Weighted RSR". This statistic is calculated by the following equation:

(Sum(SquareYards * AdjustedRSR) )   /    (Sum(SquareYards))

The values "SquareYards" and "AdjustedRSR" are both attribute fields within a feature layer that I am embedding within an HTML web page.

My workflow is the following:

Created Statistic queries (calculating sum) for the SquareYards and AdjustedRSR feature layer fields

```
 let sumSquareYards = {
      onStatisticField: "SquareYards",
      onStatisticFieldName: "SumSqYards",
      statisticType: "sum"

    }

    let sumAdjustedRSR = {
      onStatisticField: "AdjustedRSR",
      onStatisticFieldName: "SumAdjRSR",
      statisticType: "sum"

    }
```

Created a function to calculate my desired Weighted RSR statistic that I am looking to display, and then I called that function within my JS file that contains my feature layer

```
 function weightedRSR () 
    {
      value = ((sumSquareYards * sumAdjustedRSR)/(sumSquareYards))
      return "Current Road Surface Rating: " + value;

    }

    weightedRSR();
```

Note: "Current Road Surface Rating" is the terminology I am using to signify my Weighted RSR value within my web app

Finally, referenced my JS file which contains my  statistic queries and Weighted RSR function

```
<style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        zoom: 1
        ;
      }
    </style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    



  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <div id="viewDiv"> </div>
    

  

   



  


   




  </body>
</html>
```

When I test my project all I am able to see within my HTML page is my feature layer. I am unable to get the result of my WeightedRSR function to display on the HTML page.

Does my approach for creating a function which calculates the WeightedRSR function make sense? And does anyone have any insights as to why I am unable to have my function result display on my HTML page and/or tips on how I can get the function result to appear?